# Extract values from list and add to (panel) dataframe

Tags: r

while I found several answers on how to convert lists into dataframes, I'm struggling with how to extract a specific value of a list and add it to a panel dataframe such that the values of the list respect the panel structure (country, year).

I think its easier to explain this with a reproducable example:

```
# A random (panel) dataframe
df1  <- read.table(text="country   year   X1  
                         A         1990   10  
                         A         1991   12  
                         A         1992   14  
                         A         1993   17  
                         B         1990   20  
                         B         1991   18  
                         B         1992   12  
                         B         1993   14", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Then I apply the hpfilter to `X1` in the following way:

```
library(mFilter)
hpf <- dlply(df1, .(country), 
            function(x) hpfilter(x$X1, type = "lambda", freq = 6.25))
```

For those who do not have `mFilter` below the dput from `hpf`:

```
dput(hpf)
structure(list(A = structure(list(cycle = c(0.182268883056285, 
-0.0838436862058909, -0.379119276757072, 0.280694079906678), 
trend = structure(c(9.81773111694372, 12.0838436862059, 14.3791192767571, 
16.7193059200933), .Dim = c(4L, 1L)), fmatrix = structure(c    (0.280694079906678, 
-0.379119276757072, -0.0838436862058909, 0.182268883056285, 
-0.379119276757072, 0.674394867308253, -0.21143190434529, 
-0.0838436862058909, -0.0838436862058909, -0.21143190434529, 
0.674394867308253, -0.379119276757072, 0.182268883056285, 
-0.0838436862058909, -0.379119276757072, 0.280694079906678
), .Dim = c(4L, 4L)), title = "Hodrick-Prescott Filter", 
xname = "x$X1", call = hpfilter(x = x$X1, freq = 6.25, type = "lambda"), 
type = "lambda", lambda = 6.25, method = "hpfilter", x = structure(c(10L, 
12L, 14L, 17L), .Dim = c(4L, 1L))), .Names = c("cycle", "trend", 
"fmatrix", "title", "xname", "call", "type", "lambda", "method", 
"x"), class = "mFilter"), B = structure(list(cycle = c(0.335374744823564, 
0.845727617381161, -2.69757946923301, 1.51647710702829), trend = structure(c (19.6646252551764, 
17.1542723826188, 14.697579469233, 12.4835228929717), .Dim = c(4L, 
1L)), fmatrix = structure(c(0.280694079906678, -0.379119276757072, 
-0.0838436862058909, 0.182268883056285, -0.379119276757072,     0.674394867308253, 
-0.21143190434529, -0.0838436862058909, -0.0838436862058909, 
-0.21143190434529, 0.674394867308253, -0.379119276757072, 0.182268883056285, 
-0.0838436862058909, -0.379119276757072, 0.280694079906678), .Dim = c(4L, 
4L)), title = "Hodrick-Prescott Filter", xname = "x$X1", call = hpfilter(x = x$X1, 
freq = 6.25, type = "lambda"), type = "lambda", lambda = 6.25, 
method = "hpfilter", x = structure(c(20L, 18L, 12L, 14L), .Dim = c(4L, 
1L))), .Names = c("cycle", "trend", "fmatrix", "title", "xname", 
"call", "type", "lambda", "method", "x"), class = "mFilter")), split_type   = "data.frame", split_labels = structure(list(
country = c("A", "B")), .Names = "country", class = "data.frame",          row.names = c(NA, 
-2L)), .Names = c("A", "B"))
```

Now the results of the hpfilter are stored in `hpf` as a list of 2 (country A and country B) where each has a length of 10. My aim is to extract only `trend` from the list for every country and add it to the dataframe in a new column named `X1_trend`. It is easy to extract the `trend` for every single country, for example for country `A` this becomes:

```
hpf$A$trend
```

However, given I have a large dataset with many countries I hope that there is a more elegent and efficient way to extract and then add the `trend` for all countries to the dataframe `df1`. Maybe directly in one step when applying the hpfilter function?

I really appreciate any sort of help or hint to this problem!

Comment: Hi! I can't reproduce your `hpfilter` because `‘mFilter’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)`. Can you paste here the `dput(hpf)` from your example?

Comment: Hi! Please see my edited post! Let me know if it works...

Comment: Can you use `for` or `apply` loop ? 
Once you have a hpf object you can iterate over it like that for example:
`for (elem in 1:length(hpf)) {}`
you also have a name of country like 
`hpf[1] %>% names()` and values you have ?? Or it will not work in your case ?

Comment: Sorry but could you please elucidate a bit more on how to properly code the `for` loop? This for example is not working for me and only yields na values: `for (i in 1:length(hpf)) { print(i["trend"])
}`.

Comment: Yes. That was a idea to use for or apply - if you take element like that for  :  `hpf[[2]]['trend']`  - then you will have for second like that  `for (i in 1:length(hpf)) { hpf[[i]]['trend'] %>% print() }` a name you have also `hpf[1] %>% names()` in general you have a access to full structure `hpf[[2]] %>% str()`

Answer (score 1):

Ok finally I found a soloution, it is maybe not so flexible and elegent but it does what I essentially need. First add `$trend` directly to the `hpfilter` function such as:

```
hpf <- dlply(df1, .(country), 
         function(x) hpfilter(x$X1, type = "lambda", freq = 6.25)$trend)
```

Since the result of hpf is in a list of a list I make use of `unlist`:

```
# unlist hpf
unlhpf <- unlist(hpf, recursive = FALSE)

# convert into data frame
unlhpfdf <- data.frame(unlhpf)

# Add to dataframe
df1$X1_trend <- unlhpfdf$unlhpf
```

Please feel free to improve this answer.